# Angular 4 ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

I get the following error only in IE 11, I did a lot of searching, and I have uncommented the required polyfills, but still get an error. Also, it seems that I get the error in one of the components that consume API when I remove the component it works fine. So I miss something?

Seems the issue is with [focused]="i === activeIndex", when I remove it, it work?? but why

[image: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference]

my polyfill.ts

```
    /**
     * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
     * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
     *
     * This file is divided into 2 sections:
     *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
     *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
     *      file.
     *
     * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
     * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
     * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
     *
     * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
     */

    /***************************************************************************************************
     * BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */

    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


    /**
     * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
     * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
     **/
    import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



            /***************************************************************************************************
             * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
             */
            import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



            /***************************************************************************************************
             * APPLICATION IMPORTS
             */

            /**
             * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
             * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
             */
            import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
            /**
             * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
             */
            import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

the message-list.component.html

```
   <div *ngIf="!ifMessagesFound" class="container-fluid messages-wrapper" #em (selectKey)="keyChange($event)">
<div class="row actions_list">
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left:0">
        <button *ngIf="!selectAllbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default custom_all_btn" (click)="selectAllChecks(); selectAllbtn = !selectAllbtn">Select All</button>
        <button *ngIf="selectAllbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default custom_all_btn" (click)="deselectAllChecks();  selectAllbtn = !selectAllbtn">Deselect All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="text-align:right">
        <span class="result_wrapper" *ngIf="totalNumberOfItems>0 ">showing
            <span>{{totalNumberOfItems}}</span> of {{totalMessageRecords}}</span>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-5" style="text-align:right">

        <p-dropdown [options]="sortoptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedSortOption" [style]="{'width':'80px', 'cursor': 'default'}">


            <ng-template let-sortoption pTemplate="item">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height:25px;">

                    <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin-top:4px" (click)="getSortByOption(sortoption.value.code)">{{sortoption.label}}</div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>

        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="listText">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-top: 5px">
        <li *ngFor="let facet of facets;" showDelay="1000" [pTooltip]="facet.type" tooltipPosition="top" style="cursor: default; background-color:#F5F5F5"
            [ngClass]="{'active': facet.items  }" class="active">
            <a style="cursor: default" (click)="searchFacetByTypeCacheId(facet.type)">{{facet.type | facetType}}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="message-list" id="{{i}}" tabindex="0" *ngFor="let message of messages;  let i=index" [focused]="i === activeIndex"
        (click)="onAddtoMessage(message); activeIndex = i" [ngClass]="{'message-list-checked' : message.checked === true,  'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }"
        (blur)="looseFocus()" (focus)="setFocus()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="messages" value="message" [(ngModel)]="message.checked" (ngModelChange)="changedCheckbox()">
                <label for="{{message.id}}"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-11">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <td class="subjectText">
                            <span style="font-size: 13px; cursor:default">{{message.sender.name | capitalize}} </span>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
                        <span class="category_badge_0" pTooltip="Grade Category: 1" showDelay="500" hideDelay="500">{{message.gradeCategory}}</span>

                        <i *ngIf="(message.numberAttachments)>0" class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true" showDelay="500" hideDelay="500" pTooltip="Attachments: {{message.numberAttachments}}"
                            tooltipPosition="top"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <td class="subjectText">
                                    <span style=" font-size: 10px; color: grey;  cursor:default">Subject: {{message.subject}}</span>
                                </td>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
                                <ng-template ngFor let-messageTag [ngForOf]="message.tagTypes ">
                                    <span class="tags_badge_1" class="tags_badge_1" showDelay="500" hideDelay="500" pTooltip="{{messageTag.description}}" tooltipPosition="top"
                                        [ngStyle]="  messageTag?.tagColor && {'background-color': messageTag.tagColor  } || !messageTag?.tagColor && {'background-color': 'transparent', 'border': '1px solid grey' , 'color': 'black'}"
                                        showDelay="500" hideDelay="500" tooltipPosition="top">{{ messageTag.tagCount}}
                                    </span>
                                </ng-template>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
                        <span style=" font-size: 9px;  cursor:default">{{message.timeReceived}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p-paginator rows="25" totalRecords="{{totalMessageRecords}}" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,50,150,250]" (onPageChange)="paginate($event)"></p-paginator>
```

[focused] directive

```
import {Directive, Input, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[focused]'
})
export class FocusedDirective {
  @Input()
  set focused(value: boolean){
    if(value){
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scrollIntoViewIfNeeded');
    }
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}
}
```

Comment: seems the issue is with [focused]="i === activeIndex". When I remove it, it work fine

Comment: what do you want to do when using [focused]? I haven't seen this property before.

Comment: so there is a list of messages, focused is a custom directive. It actually scrolls to a focused item. Updated question with focus

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong here. hmm let me check one more time

Comment: found the issue, its scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(). Is not supported in IE11 (

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by forcing the document mode of IE to 11 or Edge.

Put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` in the header of `index.html`

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me...  even after adding this, and uncommenting the "polyfills.ts" stuff in my Angular file.   My code worked fine in Edge and Chrome, so, sod it... time to leave Internet Explorer 11 to just sit in a corner and die a slow death.